# ViewController object recreated after navigate back?

Tags: ios, segue

Now I created a new project to test unwind segue.

In Storyboard the story entry is on VC0, a button in VC0 goes to VC1 (modally), a button in VC1 goes to VC2 (modally).

VC2 has a button to dismiss itself and in the function it looks like this:

```
@IBAction func btnDismiss(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

in VC1 I added an unwind function as follows:

```
@IBAction func unwindSecondView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
    print("unwinded")
}
```

Then in storyboard I linked VC2's exit icon to unwindSecondview as action.

It works pretty well, however after I clicked "dismiss" button in VC2, VC1 appeared briefly and jumped back to VC0.

??? Anything wrong that caused jumping back to VC0?

--------------Initial question -----------------

I'm new to iOS and got a little confused for how VCs are created and activated.

Say I created 2 ViewControllers in my single view app. MainController(VC_M) and SettingsController(VC_S). I added the segues in storyboard, a setting button in VC_M goes to VC_S, VCS collects information, writes to standardDefaults, then ok button goes back to VC_M and refresh its view.

When I try to preserve some information in VC_M, I found that after I click ok button in VC_S and go back to VC_M, VC_M gets recreated and viewDidLoad() gets called. In the debugger, it shows the VC_M object (self) now has a different address in memory, so seems it's another instance of the class.

Is this a normal behavior? It's best that the old VC_M object gets saved so some data doesn't need to be reloaded. Initially I thought I could put some data loading stuff in init(), but when VC_M gets re-created init() got called, too. Some older posts suggested that ViewDidLoad() should not be called again but rather ViewDidAppear() should get called, but I'm not sure if it's the same case now.

In my case is it better to just use standardDefaults to reload everything, or is there a different kind of segue I should use? (I used push segue).

Comment: Using a push segue isn't going back, it's creating a new view controller and pushing it on.  You would use an unwind segue to go back.

Comment: Dan, I saw most examples of unwind segue uses UINavigationController. Is it a requirement? I didn't use it since my app only has two VCs.

Comment: Well you would have to be using a navigation controller if you're using a push segue, but unwind segues don't require a navigation controller.